# Тип переменной в методе расширения Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Есть такой код

```
  using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
  {
    var service = scope.Resolve<IConfigReader>(
        new NamedParameter("id", "service-identifier")
    );
  }
```

Тут переменная scope имеет тип ILifetimeScope. Однако, вроде как, в [этой](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/55396540.htm) документации сказано что метод расширения Resolve выполняется для типа this IComponentContext.
Вопрос: почему тогда метод **Resolve** применен к переменной **scope** имеющей тип **ILifetimeScope**, а не тип **IComponentContext** ?

Comment: Потому что `ILifetimeScope` наследуется [от IComponentContext](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/BA5D3489.htm)

Comment: спасибо большое . . . как всё просто оказывается